# Call function in trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

So i have a function that returns saldo. It looks like this:

```
create or replace function get_saldo(
p_knr in konto.knr%type)
return number
as
v_saldo konto.saldo%type;
begin
select saldo
into v_saldo
from konto
where knr = p_knr;
return v_saldo;
exception
when no_data_found then
return -1;
end;
```

My trigger should call get_saldo and check that the amount of money being inserted in the withdraw table is not more than money on the account. My trigger looks like this so far:

```
create or replace trigger bifer_överföring 
before update or insert 
of belopp
on insättning
for each row 
begin 
if (:new.belopp < get_saldo(p_knr)) then 
raise_application_error(-20001,'Överföringssumman är högre
än vad som finns på kontot'); 
end if; 
end;
```

Hope you guys understand what i mean. Its a school task where we need to use stored procedures. Im very new to stored procedures and i really cant seem to get the hang of it.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: 1. A variable named `p_knr` does not exist in the trigger. 2. If you want to raise an error on an amount being higher than the saldo, you need `:new.belopp > get_saldo`, not `:new.belopp < get_saldo`. 3. You return a saldo of -1 if the account does not exist. Isn't -1 a valid saldo? I think raising an exception or at least returning null would be a better reaction. 4. Your code would be more readable, if you used indention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks OK to me, except this:

```
if (:new.belopp < get_saldo(p_knr)) then 
                            -----
```

You should pass something to the function; it can't be `p_knr` but something like `:new.knr` (or whichever column exists in the `insättning` table and can be used to calculate saldo).